# Not getting CORS Headers with Spring Boot 1.4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using Athens-RC1/Boot-1.4.0

added this inner class, debugger shows the method executing

```
@Profile( "development" )
@Configuration
static class Dev extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings( final CorsRegistry registry ) {
        registry.addMapping( "/health" )
                .allowedOrigins( "http://localhost:9000" )
                .allowedHeaders( "*" )
                .allowedMethods( "GET", "OPTIONS" );
    }

}
```

but no header, an options request

```
rpf-content-manager  % curl -vvv -H"Origin: http://localhost:9000" -XOPTIONS http://localhost:8080/health                                                             slave-vi
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> OPTIONS /health HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://localhost:9000
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Application-Context: application:xenoterracide,development
< Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 04:51:41 GMT
<
```

also tried adding this to the `application-xenoterracide.properties`

```
endpoints.cors.max-age=300
endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: CORS is really only meant for XHR browser requests. The browser will send a _preflight_ OPTIONS request, with an Origin header, and _then_ the server should response to that _preflight_ request before the "real" request. If you want to use cURL just to "see it in action", then send an OPTIONS request, with an Origin header. You should then see the CORS access control response headers. Otherwise CORS doesn't affect cURL, as it doesn't have the cross origin problem XHR does.

Comment: You can read more about [CORS here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: @peeskillet hmm... I remember OPTIONS being, optional. Must be flawed memory, that said, when I do do options it still doesn't appear to be emitting the headers I told it. Also I'm more or less using curl for an example, obviously I intend to interact with a browser, but no need to use a browser to print headers for SO

Comment: @peeskillet I've done that too

Comment: I don't see it in your post

Comment: You didn't spell it right

Comment: @peeskillet because I was updating concurrently, litterally the post can't hold the number of things I've tried in my configuration. Including variations on playing with spring security and playing with the properties file. Only thing I haven't tried is adding a servlet filter and doing it manually (I know that would work)

Comment: @peeskillet updated

Comment: Yeah Im not sure. I don't really use SS. There may be something wrong with the config, I'm not sure. I was only pointing out what I saw in regards to CORS in general :-(

Comment: @peeskillet you were right about `Origin`  (half) wrong about `OPTIONS` and it needed `Access-Control-Request-Method:` that said I now am wondering why the java config doesn't appear to do what I told it to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a partial answer. My headers were wrong, but it's the lack of `'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET'` that's the real problem. Ultimately this is probably enough for me since I just needed to get this working for the local dev server.

```
 curl -vvv -H"Origin: http://localhost:9000" -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' -XGET http://localhost:8080/health                         slave-vi
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /health HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.50.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://localhost:9000
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< X-Application-Context: application:xenoterracide,development
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:9000
< Vary: Origin
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 05:27:09 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"status":"UP"}
```

Comment: This isn't really much of an answer. Please be descriptive, usually providing code, when you answer questions-- especially your own.

Comment: I did the problem was client side. The curl is code

Comment: @xenoterracide Your curl is different on two things: the addition of header and changing method to `GET`. You should still use `-XOPTIONS`, does it work ?